# I had to change my html file to php for it to work

Tags: php, html

I am making a html5 app in android, I had to change my html file extension to `.php` for it to work. I don't want to do that. How do I get php to work w/o changing my whole file? thanks

```
<?php

$myarray[] = "noticable";
$filename = "geo.php";
$mystring = implode("\n", $myarray);
$numbytes = file_put_contents($filename, $mystring . "\n",    FILE_APPEND);
print "$numbytes bytes written\n";

?>
```

I want `index.html` not `index.php`

Comment: Why it didnt work? What information appear? What u used to opening the file, browser base? App base ?

Comment: create a `.htaccess` file in your root the add this to it `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html`